# Getting error while creating multiple file in python

Tags: python, json

I'm creating two files using python script, first file is JSON and second one is HTML file, my below is creating json file but while creating HTML file I'm getting error. Could someone help me to resolve the issue? I'm new to Python script so it would be really appreciated if you could suggest some solution

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import json


JsonResponse = '[{"status": "active", "due_date": null, "group": "later", "task_id": 73286}]'


def create(JsonResponse):
    print JsonResponse
    print 'creating new  file'
    try:
        jsonFile = 'testFile.json'
        file = open(jsonFile, 'w')
        file.write(JsonResponse)
        file.close()
        with open('testFile.json') as json_data:
            infoFromJson = json.load(json_data)
            print infoFromJson
            htmlReportFile = 'Report.html'
            htmlfile = open(htmlReportFile, 'w')
            htmlfile.write(infoFromJson)
            htmlfile.close()
    except:
        print 'error occured'
        sys.exit(0)


create(JsonResponse)
```

I used below online Python editor to execute my code:

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php

Comment: Using `with open` in some places but not others is ... uncanny.

Answer (score 0):

```
infoFromJson = json.load(json_data)
```

Here, `json.load()` will expect a valid json data as `json_data`. But the `json_data` you provided are not valid json, it's a simple string(`Hello World!`). So, you are getting the error.

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Update:

In your code you should get the error:

> TypeError: expected a character buffer object

That's because, the content you are writing to the file needs to be string, but in place of that, you have a list of dictionary.

Two way to solve this. Replace the line:

```
htmlfile.write(infoFromJson)
```

To either this:

```
htmlfile.write(str(infoFromJson))
```

To make `infoFromJson` a string.

Or use the `dump` utility of `json` module:

```
json.dump(infoFromJson, json_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I gave a proper json now - I've update my post with valid json in my message but still I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete `Try...except` statement, you will see errors below:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Ithink/wechatProjects/django_wx_joyme/app/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    create(JsonResponse)
  File "/Volumes/Ithink/wechatProjects/django_wx_joyme/app/test.py", line 22, in create
    htmlfile.write(infoFromJson)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object`

Errors occurred because `htmlfile.write` need `string type` ,but `infoFromJson` is a list .
So,change `htmlfile.write(infoFromJson)` to `htmlfile.write(str(infoFromJson))` will avoid errors!